# Why is "isModifiedByPowermock returning false with @PrepareForTest?

Tags: java, powermock, junit5

Using Powermock 2.0.7 (powermock-api-mockito2, powermock-core, powermock-module-junit4) and mockito-core (3.3.3). I thought I had created a comparable test scenario in a separate project (which worked), but something else must be missing.

Library class to be mocked:

```
  public class CommonConstants {
      private ConfigurationDataImpl configurationData;
      private static Properties sysProperties;
      private static Map<String, String> sysPermissions;

      public CommonConstants(ConfigurationDataImpl configurationData) {
        this.configurationData = configurationData;
      }

      public void init() {
        sysProperties = this.configurationData.getSysParams();
        sysPermissions = this.configurationData.getSysPermissions();
      }

      public static String getSysProperties(String key) {
        return sysProperties.getProperty(key);
      }

      public static String getSysPermissions(String key) {
        return (String)sysPermissions.get(key);
      }
}
```

In my test, I have:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({CommonConstants.class})    <==== class that evidently is not modified!
class MyServiceTest {

    public MyServiceTest() {}

    @Mock
    private MyDao myDao;

    @InjectMocks
    private MyService myService;

    @Test
    void retrieveUsers() {
        RequestPayload rp = returnPayload();
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(CommonConstants.class);    <==== EXCEPTION
        when(CommonConstants.getSysProperties(HOURS_TO_REGISTER)).thenReturn("24");
...
```

In the service code, I have:

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class MyService {

    MyDao myDao;

    public MyService(MyDao myDao) {
        this.myDao = myDao;
    }

    public UserListResponse retrieveUsers(RequestPayload requestPayload, String customer) {
        List<User> users = myDao.getPtdUsers(queryParams, customer, totalRecords);
        int hoursToExpire = Integer.parseInt(CommonConstants.getSysProperties(HOURS__TO_REGISTER));
...
```

Am I leaving out something? All help appreciated.

Comment: If you’re really using JUnit5 (Jupiter) then the answer is: Powermock does not work with It. RunWith is a JUnit4 mechanism.

Comment: Finally had a chance to re-examine the standalone test I did and the code above. As @johanneslink pointed out, it's a JUnit5 problem. The gotcha was the package that the Test annotation was taken from. My standalone test used org.junit.Test - JUnit4; but my code above is using the Test annotation from JUnit5! Once I made the change to use JUnit4 annotations, all worked. Good lesson, though annoying!